# Invoke Pester returning with zero results

Tags: powershell, pester

I have a Pester Script with is running a few smoke tests for my API. When I run the Invoke-Pester, I get the Logo and the tests run fine. However at the end of the log I get `Tests Passed: 0, Failed: 0, Skipped: 0, Pending: 0, Inconclusive: 0` and when I try to output as a NUnitXML there are not results in there either

**Command:**

```
Invoke-Pester -Script @{Path = 'Path\testscript.ps1'; Arguments = '200', 'application/json; charset=utf-8'} -OutputFormat NUnitXml -OutputFile ".\TestsResults.xml"
```

**Script:**

```
param(
    [string]$HttpCode,
    [string]$ContentType
)

Import-Module Pester -Force

Describe 'API Smoke Tests' { 
    Context "Direct Endpoint Smoke Test: $Uri" {
        It 'HTTP Code Should be equal to "200"' {
            $HttpCode | Should -Be 200
        }
        It 'Content Type Should be equal to "application/json; charset=utf-8"' {
            $ContentType | Should -Be "application/json; charset=utf-8"
        }
    }

}
```

**Console Log:**

```
    ____            __
   / __ \___  _____/ /____  _____
  / /_/ / _ \/ ___/ __/ _ \/ ___/
 / ____/  __(__  ) /_/  __/ /
/_/    \___/____/\__/\___/_/
Pester v4.9.0
Executing all tests in 'Path\testscript.ps1'

Executing script Path\testscript.ps1

Describing API Smoke Tests

  Context Direct Endpoint Smoke Test: 
    [+] HTTP Code Should be equal to "200" 10ms
    [+] Content Type Should be equal to "application/json; charset=utf-8" 6ms
Tests completed in 1.59s
Tests Passed: 0, Failed: 0, Skipped: 0, Pending: 0, Inconclusive: 0
```

Comment: I ran your code example and it worked fine for me.  Is there something you've not mentioned above?  Is there anything in the 'code....' section that might cause an issue?  Can you create a very simple Pester test that avoids your own code and get these working?  Maybe some examples from the Pester Wiki.

Comment: @boxdog I created a very simple script and I am still getting the same results as before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can reproduce your issue with the following scripts:

**go.ps1**

```bsh
Import-Module -Name ".\Pester-4.9.0\Pester.psd1"

Invoke-Pester -Script @{
                  Path = ".\script.ps1"
                  Arguments = @( "200", "application/json; charset=utf-8" )
              } `
              -OutputFormat "NUnitXml" `
              -OutputFile   ".\Results.xml"
```

**script.ps1**

```bsh
param
(
    [string] $HttpCode,
    [string] $ContentType
)

Import-Module -Name .\Pester-4.9.0\Pester.psd1 -Force

Describe 'API Smoke Tests' { 
    Context "Direct Endpoint Smoke Test: $Uri" {
        It 'HTTP Code Should be equal to "200"' {
            $HttpCode | Should -Be 200
        }
        It 'Content Type Should be equal to "application/json; charset=utf-8"' {
            $ContentType | Should -Be "application/json; charset=utf-8"
        }
    }
}
```

and then:

```
C:\> powershell .\go.ps1
    ____            __
   / __ \___  _____/ /____  _____
  / /_/ / _ \/ ___/ __/ _ \/ ___/
 / ____/  __(__  ) /_/  __/ /
/_/    \___/____/\__/\___/_/
Pester v4.9.0
Executing all tests in '.\script.ps1'

Executing script .\script.ps1

Describing API Smoke Tests

  Context Direct Endpoint Smoke Test:
    [+] HTTP Code Should be equal to "200" 114ms
    [+] Content Type Should be equal to "application/json; charset=utf-8" 7ms
Tests completed in 0.99s
Tests Passed: 0, Failed: 0, Skipped: 0, Pending: 0, Inconclusive: 0
```

Note - `Tests Passed: 0`

The problem is that you're importing Pester from within a script that's already running in Pester. The answer is to remove the `Import-Module` from script.ps1 and then you get:

```
C:\> powershell .\go.ps1
    ____            __
   / __ \___  _____/ /____  _____
  / /_/ / _ \/ ___/ __/ _ \/ ___/
 / ____/  __(__  ) /_/  __/ /
/_/    \___/____/\__/\___/_/
Pester v4.9.0
Executing all tests in '.\script.ps1'

Executing script .\script.ps1

  Describing API Smoke Tests

    Context Direct Endpoint Smoke Test:
      [+] HTTP Code Should be equal to "200" 106ms
      [+] Content Type Should be equal to "application/json; charset=utf-8" 5ms
Tests completed in 623ms
Tests Passed: 2, Failed: 0, Skipped: 0, Pending: 0, Inconclusive: 0
```

Note - `Tests Passed: 2`

I *think* the symptom you're seeing is part of how Pester accumulates test results - it stores them in a global state, so *maybe* what's happening is something along the lines of the tests are actually running in the `script.ps1` Pester module (and that's what you're seeing the test output from), but the test summary at the end is coming from the `go.ps1` Pester module where zero tests have run...

That's just speculation though - ultimately, don't import Pester from within your Pester tests and things should just work...